# What was the fundamental error of Bayesian statistics according to Fisher?

Tags: bayesian, ronald-fisher

Fisher wrote:

> "the theory of inverse probability is founded upon an error, and must
>   be wholly rejected"

I wonder what was Fisher's reasoning and what error he means in particular.

The quote is from "Statistical methods for research workers" (Fisher 1925) but I don't have access to that book, and what I found from Fisher from that time uses terminology which I am not acquainted with (e.g. "inverse probability" referring to bayesian methods).

Comment: You may be interested in reading this https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1340370565

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the source of the quote? (You may actually find Fisher's reasoning at the same place.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa I quote it after "Scientific rethinking" by Richard McElreath. The quote is from a book published in 1925 to which I have no access ("Statistical methods for research workers").

Comment: @Tim Yes, I have seen that publication, but I find it incomprehensible. Half of the time I don't know what the author means. I think it requires knowing intimately the works of Fisher, which I don't.

Comment: Fisher was brilliant about so many things.  This is not one of them.